# Update column value when their other column values are same

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image]

The Problem is, StudentId in row number 2 should be 1 because their Name and Father Name are the same. Similarly, StudentId in row number 4 should be 3 because Name and Father Name are the same

I have revised my query according to my requirement as I have to update my student_id when student_name, student dob, student father, email, countryId, and skype id will same now updated query will be

```
  Merge into student_new_Backup
     using ( select min(student_id) as stid, student_name, student_father,student_dob,email_id,skype_id,country
             from student_new_Backup 
              group by student_name, student_father,student_dob,email_id,skype_id,country) a
     on (student_new_Backup.student_name= a.student_name
          and student_new_Backup.student_father=a.student_father
          and student_new_Backup.student_dob=a.student_dob
unfortunately no student_id is update
          and student_new_Backup.email_id=a.email_id
          and student_new_Backup.skype_id=a.skype_id
          and student_new_Backup.country=a.country)
      when matched then 
           UPDATE SET student_new_Backup.student_id=a.stid
           ;
           commit;
```

unfortunately, no student_id is an update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
update t
    set studentId = (select min(t2.studentId)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.name = t.name and t2.fathername = t.fathername
                    );
```

EDIT:

If you want `NULL` safe comparisons, then you need be be explicit:

```
update t
    set studentId = (select min(t2.studentId)
                     from t t2
                     where (t2.name = t.name or t2.name is null and t.name is null) and
                           (t2.fathername = t.fathername or t2.fathername is null and t.fathername is null)
                    );
```

Comment: sir i have also try as you suggested but it is taking too long to update more than an hour,so i had stop my query can you rewrite your code according my given table name and column name

Comment: sir if name or father name has null value your code also update studentId null .

Comment: @AbdulRaheem . . . Your question does not mention `NULL` values, so one can only assume that you are using them as they are defined in SQL -- i.e., `NULL` values are not equal.  If you want them to compare as equal, you need to add explicit logic for that.

Answer (score 2):

you can use merge  for update

```
 Merge into table_name
 using ( select min(studentId) as stid, Name, fathername
         from table_name 
          group by Name, fathername) a
 on (table_name.Name= a.Name
      and table_name.fatherName=a.fatherName)
  when matched then 
       UPDATE SET table_name.studentId=a.stid
```

[online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6187d13a2194d7c60e9874fe530173c)

Comment: please have a look sir, i have write code as you suggested but no student_id is update

Comment: @AbdulRaheem https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6187d13a2194d7c60e9874fe530173c check this demo

Comment: i am sorry @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin your code perfectly work on demo but on my condition apply it don't . first answer has done the job but little issue in that is if any condition column has null value it will set student_id null can you please look into Gordon Linoff code ?